# css menu hover displaying submenu out of alignment

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have an issue where the leftside navigation menu has submenus on hover and is out of alignment.

```
DIV#nav-cat UL UL.level2 {
z-index: 8007;
position: absolute;
border-bottom-color: #b0ccdc;
border-right-width:1px;
background-color: #e8f1f6;
border-top-color: #b0ccdc;
width:132px;
display: none;
border-top-width:1px;
border-bottom-width:1px;
border-right-color: #b0ccdc;
border-left-color: #b0ccdc;
border-left-width:1px;
top: -2px;
left: 178px;
}
```

The first menu "Electronics" displays the submenu correctly by the side. Another menu "Apple accessories" is for example displaying submenu (Mobile case) out of alignment. It is displaying at the top rather than by the side of the menu.

The css classes are

```
<ul class='level1'> and <ul class='level2'>.
```

I am unable to locate the issue. Kindly guide me to correct the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set that element to `position: absolute` with  `top: -2p;` This is why it is located where it is. So to answer you question 'Kindly guide me to correct the css.' The offending CSS is below

```
DIV#nav-cat UL UL.level2 {
z-index: 8007;
position: absolute;
border-bottom-color: #b0ccdc;
border-right-width: 2px;
background-color: #e8f1f6;
border-top-color: #b0ccdc;
width: 175px;
display: none;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 3px;
border-right-color: #b0ccdc;
border-left-color: #b0ccdc;
border-left-width: 1px;
top: -2px;
left: 178px;
}
```

To fix the issue you need to set the parent to `position: relative`

```
DIV#nav-cat LI.submenu {
position: static; <-- remove this
position: relative; <-- add this
display: block;
background: url(../../../../../includes/templates/tpl_default/images/categoriescss_bg.gif) bottom no-repeat;
}
```

I have tested the above code in a Firefox console and it works perfectly.

Comment: So how can i get it aligned with the main menu.

Comment: if you change your CSS `DIV#nav-cat LI.submenu` from `position: static;` to `position: relative;` all your issues will be resolved.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. But the Apple accessories submenu is displaying with height reduced, since there is only a single item. How can i correct that ?

Comment: You can set a `min-height` to an element.

Comment: Thank you. Changed line-height:27px; and min-height: 27px;

Answer (score 1):

## DEMO

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="submenu">
    <ul class="level2"></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.submenu{
    position:relative;
    height:15px
}
.submenu:hover > .level2{  /*target this li level2*/
    position:absolute;
    left:183px; /*width of submenu*/
    top:0;
}
```